# Create animated PNGs (APNG)

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editing, animation

Safari 8 [supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=apng) the [unofficial APNG extension](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification) to the standardized PNG format.

Most popular image editors (on any platform) do not support APNG (yet). Plugins are mostly available for Windows software only. Searching Macupdate returned nil as well.

How can I generate an APNG from a series of still PNGs (not from a video file) on OS X? (Although I understand the file structure, I’m hesitant to do it manually.)

Comment: There are some python-based options if you search around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used [APNG Assembler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apngasm/) for Windows. It appears that the GUI version is only for Windows, but command line versions exist for both Linux and Mac OS X. Using the CLI version (or writing a UI wrapper for it, if you have any development experience) may be a possibility.

Alternatively, you can use an online service such as [this online APNG Assembler](http://littlesvr.ca/apng/assembler/assembler.php). I cannot vouch for the effectiveness of this solution, however.

Comment: A year later, I finally came round to accept this as an answer, although using the terminal never feels really “macish”. There is something on the App Store now, though, which looks like a GUI wrapper to apngasm: [PNG Animator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/png-animator/id899480442).

Answer (score 2):

[APNGb](https://macdownload.informer.com/apngb/download/) is a free APNG assembler with a Mac GUI. I just tested it on macOS Monterey and it worked well. Development is active (the last update was less than a week ago at the time of this writing). You simply drag-drop your still PNG frames, set the animation speed, and save. Quick and simple!

There are three compression types to choose from. I tested it with the default 7zip. The resulting .png file displayed fine in all three browsers I tested on (Firefox, Safari, Chrome). I can't speak to the differences between the compression types, but they should all work. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/apng) does not mention any compatibility issues with one APNG compression type versus another.

A few usability quirks to be aware of (as of v2.0.1):

- Frame rate is specified in 10ths of a second per frame, which is a bit unconventional. So if you want your animation to hold each frame for 2 seconds, you would input `20 / 10`. For 100 milliseconds it would be `1 / 10`. For 24 FPS: (1 sec / 24 frames) * 10 = 0.416666666666667, therefor `0.416666666666667 / 10`
- Instead of `File > Save As` or `File > Export`, you must select all of your frames, then click the mysterious black square in the upper-left part of the window to save your animated .png file so that it becomes a black triangle, and then click that triangle. Apparently this is a *square = stop*, *triangle = play* sort of logic.
- The application window cannot be dragged if you click the wrong part of it at the top, because some areas are reserved for text messages. (Around where it usually says "Idle..." Solution: Click elsewhere until you find a draggable area.)
- You can't specify the file name of your resulting APNG. You can only specify the folder to save it to. It will be named `apngb-animated.png`. Rename this file as soon as you create it, because any existing file of that name will be overwritten without prompting the next time you save an APNG.

There is also a modal for de-compiling an existing APNG into individual .png frames. It can be accessed by clicking the icon resembling a stack of paper on the left sidebar.

All in all, the app is easy to use. The present usability issues are not show-stoppers by any means. The files the app puts out seem to animate without any problems. And I'm optimistic that the app will only get better, as development is ongoing.